# Which legacy browsers are still in use due to hardware limitations?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I want to make sure that my web app is accessible by people with limited hardware. Are there people that ***have to*** run legacy versions of browsers due to hardware limitations? Which browsers are used?

Comment: Plenty of people just use old, bad browsers because they don't know of anything else. Unfortunately, that means you'll be in IE6 land. Before you go down that route, think carefully about how much support for outdated hardware and browsers really matters to your userbase. Support of legacy is going to make anything you do take much more time and effort to make it work.

Comment: I am not sure why there are downvotes, this question has valid business case behind it - there are a lot of people/businesses using antequated hardware and old browser versions.  I posted the link below which has a lot of stats.

Comment: I'm sure *someone*, *somewhere*, can't upgrade their hardware/software (maybe there are on Windows 3.11 with NS 3.04 Gold?). But the problem is .. there is no way to quantify this other than "there is likely such a case, even if it is of no consequence". The real question - which is a *business decision* - is which browsers are *you* going to support? Browser trends/usage across different demographics - e.g what do *your* customers use? - can be used to make an informed choice.

Comment: Windows XP is still very relevant in the business world (and personal PC world) and maxes out at IE 8, so you should absolutely be testing IE 8+.

Comment: also consider sealed devices like iPhone3, nintendo Wii, Android 2.3, etc. Old computers CAN run firefox, but old devices cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most restrictive variable in the war on letting old browsers die, is the limits that Microsoft implemented around OS support of the various versions of IE.  For example:

- Windows 2000 only supports up through IE6
- Windows XP only supports up through IE8
- Windows Vista only supports up to IE9

(see here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_versions#Windows )

As a result, in order to update their versions of Internet Explorer, many, many, **MANY** computer users out there would be forced to update their computer's entire operating system or even their computer, in order to support a new version of the operating system.  For many people, the amount of money that that costs is simply not worth the benefits gained from the upgrade.

So, they get stuck with old versions of IE and we have to support them.   :)

In the end, you cant support everyone . . . use the available stats out there for OS and browser usage to determine which percentage of the population you want to support, and then support the resulting subset of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good documentation of browsers/versions that are in use, and % of users.  You can drill down into each browser to find more information.

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: That has to be one of the worst stats I have ever seen (being on/by w3schools doesn't earn any immediate trust either). It's near-useless to compare trends without major-version breakdowns and a demographic overlay - pay attention to the note at the end.

Comment: @user2864740 instead of criticizing, perhaps you could provide a better, more robust answer?  I'm tired of all the useless comments of people just slamming each other on this board.

Comment: I did. I voted to close the question (as I feel there is no "good" SO answer). Also, on SO, it's good to separate oneself from the answer one has posted, and especially some data on an external link! I only spoke critically of the data.